# Mapping cylinder is a pushout

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Mapping cylinder is a pushout where the definition of Mapping cylinder is the following: For given two topological spaces $X,Y$ and a continuous map $f:X\to Y$, a mapping cylinder $M_f$ is $X\times I\amalg Y/f(x)\sim (x,0)$ where $x\in X$.

i.e. I want to show that if $p:X\to X\times I$ by $x\mapsto (x,0)$ and $\varphi_1:Y\to M_f$ and $\varphi_2:X\times I\to M_f$ are induced maps and For given topological space $Z$ and two maps $\psi_1:Y\to Z$ and $\psi:X\times I\to Z$ such that the following diagram commute,
[image: ddd]

then there is a unique map $\varphi:M_f\to Z$ that makes the diagram commute. Could you help?

By the way, I'm not familiar with Categroy theory languages so the statement could be absurd

Comment: Hint: note that the mapping cylinder is defined as an coequalizer of a coproduct (of which maps?). Read online how pushouts can be constructed from coproducts and coequalizers, this is exactly how the mapping cylinder is constructed. If you want to prove directly that the above is a pushout, then you will have to use the properties of coproducts and quotients /coequalizers anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the canonical inclusions $j_1 : Y \hookrightarrow Y \sqcup (X \times I)$ and $j_2 : X \times I \hookrightarrow Y \sqcup (X \times I)$. Now, from $\psi_1 : Y \to Z$ and $\psi_2 : X \times I \to Z$ one has a map $\psi : Y \sqcup (X \times I) \to Z$ so that $$\psi \circ j_1 = \psi_1 \quad \& \quad \psi \circ j_2 = \psi_2.$$ Additionally, if we assume that $\psi_1 \circ f = \psi_2 \circ p$, then $\psi$ identifies $j_1(f(x))$ with $j_2(x,0)$ for all $x \in X$, so $\psi$ factors through $M_f$: $$\varphi : M_f \to Z; \quad [z] \mapsto \psi(z)$$ (check that this is well-defined!).

Comment: You must be my guardian angel! thanks :)